# Problemas ao gravar duas informações na mesma posição do array

Tags: array, ionic, ionic3, ionic2

Bem, estou desenvolvendo um app com `ionic 3`. Estou enfrentando problemas, pois preciso mostrar na mesma coluna, o produto e seu valor :

> Produto - 350(valor)

Mas, ele está armazenando na posição 1, o produto, e na posição 2 o seu valor.

Segue o código `TS`:

```
  for (let i = 0; i <= this.vetValores.length; i++) {

    if (this.vetValores.indexOf(element, this.valTot)) {
      this.vetValores.push(element, this.valTot);
      this.vetValores[i + 1];
      break;
    }
```

Código `HTML` :

```
 <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let prod of vetValores">
             <ion-row>            
                  {{prod}} {{prod.valTot}} 
              </ion-row>

            </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
```

Comment: o que tem em element?

Comment: Element equivale ao produto informado

Comment: acho que o ideal seria você criar um atributo no produto chamado ValorTotal e colocar o this.valTot neste atributo, pois do jeito que você esta usando o push, ele vai ter vai mostar como vocês esta dizendo que esta mostrando, um após o outro, pois o push aceita N elementos: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_push.htm

Comment: let val = this.valTot;

    if (this.vetCarrinhoAux.indexOf(element, val) === -1) {
      this.vetCarrinho.push(element, val);